# Error while using the readfromexcel component in Intellibot Studio

Tags: rpa, intellibot, intellibot-studio, intellibot-robot

I am using the readfromexcel component under Data Reader category. I already installed the microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 and re-tried. However, it gives the same error. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please install the

> AccessDatabaseEngine 32bit

Note: Before installing this download, you must first remove any previous versions of the Access Database Engine from your computer by using Uninstall a Program in the Control Panel.

Click the link below: 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

Select AccessDatabaseEngine.exe

For your reference
[image]